# How can you sum up a variable according to the input of a radio input?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm programming a little quiz that shows you which of the four possible products suits you best.

The different questions are asked with radio inputs and each has the appropriate value

```html
<input class="answer__input" type="radio" id="question1" value="product1" />
<input class="answer__input" type="radio" id="question1" value="product2" />
<input class="answer__input" type="radio" id="question1" value="product3" />
<input class="answer__input" type="radio" id="question1" value="product4" />
```

In JavaScript i have 4 Variables:

```js
var product1 = 0  
var product2 = 0  
var product3 = 0  
var product4 = 0
```

Now i want that each time an answer is selected, the respective variable increases by 1

After 10 questions it could look like this:

```js
var product1= 2
var product2 = 4
var product3 = 3
var product4 = 1
```

At the end of the Quiz i want to output the variable which is the biggest.

How can i do this in JavaScript? I would be very grateful for that help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same `id` 4 times, and you must add `name` to radio input. I've rebuilt your html:

```html
1 product<input class="answer__input question1" name="question1" type="radio" id="product1" value="product1" /><br>
2 product<input class="answer__input question1" name="question1" type="radio" id="product2" value="product2" /><br>
3 product<input class="answer__input question1" name="question1" type="radio" id="product3" value="product3" /><br>
4 product<input class="answer__input question1" name="question1" type="radio" id="product4" value="product4" /><br>
```

Now I've also added an event listener for the `change` event using a `for` loop on all products. In the function, I checked what option the user clicked and incremented the corresponding value.

```js
var product1 = 0;
var product2 = 0;
var product3 = 0;
var product4 = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   document.getElementById(`product${i}`).addEventListener('change', e => {
      if (e.target.value === 'product1') product1++;
      else if (e.target.value === 'product2') product2++;
      else if (e.target.value === 'product3') product3++;
      else if (e.target.value === 'product4') product4++;

      console.log(product1, product2, product3, product4);
   });
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your answer! It worked! The only problem that i have now is that it just work with one question.  How would you name the `id` so that it works a multiple times?